# Collect Info from user in Workflow 2010 under SP2013 creates tasks but not assigns it

Tags: workflow

Having issues with Collect Info from a user in Workflow 2010 running under SharePoint 2013.

Workflow has steps with Collect info from users and several approvals.

Collect info creates task and supposed to assign the task to a user to collect info from. The problem is it only works for users who happen to be Farm admins, for anybody else the **task is created but left unassigned**.

When workflow moves to approval steps, approval  tasks are created and assigned properly.

In every case the workflow is started and runs under same credentials.

Same behavior on PROD and DEV farms.

Ideas?